# The page shows hidden items off the screen in mobile mode

Tags: html, css

I trying to resolve it, but i dont know that problems is with menu, or icon of chat(using tawk.to)
The page is also online on [www.niebieskiczat.pl](http://www.niebieskiczat.pl)
I never had this problem, but i think i change something and now i got this like that, or maybe tawk.to change somethink? The hamburger menu should appear on the regular website and on the mobile. Now on PC working god, but on mobile i got problem like on picture. Here is code for CSS navbar

```
   .menuToggle {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  right: 120px;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.menuToggle input {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: -5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

.menuToggle span {
  display: block;
  width: 33px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  background: #cdcdcd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  z-index: 1;
  transform-origin: 4px 0px;
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1),
    background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1), opacity 0.55s ease;
}

.menuToggle span:first-child {
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}

.menuToggle span:nth-last-child(2) {
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}

.menuToggle input:checked ~ span {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
  background: #232323;
}

.menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(3) {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
}

.menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(2) {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
}

.menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  margin: -80px 0 0 0;
  padding: 50px;
  padding-top: 105px;
  right: -150px;
  background: lightblue;
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform: translate(100%, 0);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1);
}

.menu li {
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.menuToggle input:checked ~ ul {
  transform: none;
  opacity: 1;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #menu {
    transform: none;
    opacity: 0;

    transition: opacity 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1);
  }
}
```

And HTML

```
<nav role='navigation'>
        <div class="menuToggle">
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <ul class="menu">
                <a href="pages/about.html">
                    <li>O nas</li>
                </a>
                <a href="pages/howtotalk.html">
                    <li>Jak rozmawiać?</li>
                </a>
                <a href="pages/contacts.html">
                    <li>Przydatne kontakty</li>
                </a>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

[image: the page shows hidden items off the screen]

Comment: try

@media and screen and (max-width:766px){
 .menu{
 display:none;
}
}

Comment: @AlaksandarJesusGene that would not solve the problem completely bcz transition will be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your menu class.
It will solve your problem.

```
.menu {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
@media and screen and (max-width:766px){ .menu{ display:none; } }
```

[image]